# Lumen 5.2 debug mode is not working

Tags: php, debugging, config, lumen

I have a problem with lumen's exception debug output.
I have enabled debug mode, but it doesn't seem to work properly.

My config/app.php:

```
<?php
return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Encryption Key
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This key is used by the Illuminate encrypter service and should be set
    | to a random, 32 character string, otherwise these encrypted strings
    | will not be safe. Please do this before deploying an application!
    |
    */
    'env' => 'local',
    'debug' => true,

    'key' => env('APP_KEY', 'SomeRandomString!!!'),

    'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Locale Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The application locale determines the default locale that will be used
    | by the translation service provider. You are free to set this value
    | to any of the locales which will be supported by the application.
    |
    */
    'locale' => env('APP_LOCALE', 'en'),
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Fallback Locale
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The fallback locale determines the locale to use when the current one
    | is not available. You may change the value to correspond to any of
    | the language folders that are provided through your application.
    |
    */
    'fallback_locale' => env('APP_FALLBACK_LOCALE', 'en'),

];
```

In bootstrap.php i have

```
$app->configure('app');
```

So, i cheked - the config file is loaded succesfully.

But when my app throwing an exception lumen just output - "Whoops, looks like something went wrong."

There is no any debug info.

What's the problem?

P.S i don't want to use .env config file.

Answer (score 0):

Could you put up more information from your log?

**As for config file**

lumen is using Dotenv to manage configure files. The default config file .env is loaded in boostrap/app.php as:

```
(new Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__.'/../'))->load();
```

Therefore, you can define your own config file path and name by:

```
(new Dotenv\Dotenv($your_config_file_real_path, $your_config_file_name))->load();
```

Note: you can use multiple config files if you want by loading different files like:

```
(new Dotenv\Dotenv($your_config_file_real_path1, $your_config_file_name1))->load();
(new Dotenv\Dotenv($your_config_file_real_path2, $your_config_file_name2))->load();
```